# Best way to load my module phtml only if system config is enabled

Tags: magento2, template, configuration

I am trying to override `/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/view.phtm`l by `di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View" type="Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\Order\View"/>
```

The Block i added is

```
namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\Order;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;


class View extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\View
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
     * @param array $data
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    parent::__construct($context,$registry,$httpContext, $paymentHelper, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }




    public function getTemplate() 
    {
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $customOrderViewConfig = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('customorderview/enabled/fieldid', $storeScope);
            if ($customOrderViewConfig) {
                return 'corder/view.phtml';
            }
            return parent::getTemplate();
    }

    public function setTemplate($template)
    {
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $customOrderViewConfig = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('customorderview/enabled/fieldid', $storeScope);
            if ($customOrderViewConfig == 1) {
            $_template = 'corder/view.phtml';
            }
        else
        {
                $template = 'Magento_Sales::order/view.phtml';
        }
        return parent::setTemplate($_template);
    }
}
```

This is working fine , but i want to load my Phtml file when my module is enabled.

I tried

- If condition in phtml file looks bad.
- No way to add ifConfig in layout ( There is no layout in my module ).
- beforeToHtml function in block ( Not working ).
- setTemplate function in block ( Not working ).

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of this variants:

Override **getTemplate** method:

```
public function getTemplate() 
{
    $isEnabled = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'module/path/enabled',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    if ($isEnabled) {
        //Return your template
        return 'path/to/custom/template.phtml';
    }

    return parent::getTemplate();
}
```

Override **toHtml** method:

```
public function toHtml()
{
    $isEnabled = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'module/path/enabled',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    if (!$isEnabled) {
        //Return your template
        return parent::toHtml();
    }

    //Some actions
}
```

And I am surprised, why not work **setTemplate**, but it working for me:

```
public function setTemplate($template)
{
    if ($isEnabled) {
        //Your custom template
        $template = 'path/to/template.phtml';
    }

    return parent::setTemplate($template);
}
```

This all working for me, and i hope, that one of these methods help you.

Comment: @ Irop Thanks for quick reply, when i tried getTemplate , am getting two templates into front end. setTemplate and toHtml functions are still not working. I updated my Block i used above function individually but i mentioned for reference.

Comment: When  you set template in **$_template** it working for you? In these case you can try set template in `__constructor ` : `if ($moduleEnabled) { $this->_template = 'path/to/template.phtml'; }`. Maybe it help for you

Comment: @ Irop I have tried inside __constructor also but no luck.